# Wi-Fi disconnect and has to reboot my computer to fix

Tags: wireless-networking, reboot, wifi-configuration, device-manager, wifi-driver

I have my ASUS laptop
When its on for a while i get the WiFi not working
it disconnect me and when I try to reconnect again it does not
The only way to resolve this is by restarting the laptop.

I tried to disable the wifi card from Devices menu and enable it back, but that does not make the WiFi work again

I had to restart to fix it.

I wonder if anyone has a fast solution to get the WiFi working without the need of restarting the laptop.

P.S. 
* The Router is OK, I got other devices connected to the same Router and no problems at all.
* When I get this problem I try to connect to other routers (WiFi connections) and nothing works.

Thanks

Comment: Sometimes hibernating can reset hardware. If it doesn't work first time, try disconnecting power and battery for at least 10 seconds while hibernated. Make sure it is hibernation and not sleep. Also, if you're on Windows, try the network troubleshooter.

Comment: No, it is not during hibernating, it happens while the laptop is on

Comment: That is not what I said: I was suggesting hibernation as a possible fix for the problem without rebooting - still an interruption, but a lot faster than restarting.